# Simply AB + ′B using boolean algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

If I have the following function: AB + 'B , using karnaugh it is simplified to A +'B

What I want is to make this simplification using boolean algebra. What law is used in boolean algebra to transform AB + 'B to A + 'B?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know De Morgan's laws?

Comment: @roberttimmer-arends what Morgan law could be used in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can justify the steps below.
\begin{align}
AB+B'
&= AB + (A+A')B'\\
&= AB + AB' +A'B'\\
&=(AB + AB') + (AB'+A'B')\\
&= A(B+B') + (A+A')B'\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}
(Can you take it from here?)

Comment: I don't understand what you did in this step: =AB+AB′+A′B′=(AB+AB′)+(AB′+A′B′), why you have repeated AB' two times? 1+2+3 is not the same as (1+2)+(2+3)...

Comment: @Lechius In Boolean algebra, $x+x=x$, didn't you know? If you didn't know the binary operations are idempotent, you hardly could ever reach the result. What do you really know about Boolean algebras?

Comment: yes, I have just seen it, I have understood, thanks

Comment: I have thought of making this also that is faster : AB+ B' = AB + AB' + B' = A(B+B') + B' = A + B'. Is this correct?

Comment: @Lechius It gives a different result, and that is a good hint that something might be wrong, as $A+B'\neq A+B$, most of the times. The wrong equality is, of course, the first one (since all the others are correct).

Comment: I think you saw the not edited version, I wrote it wrong, I have edited it and the result now is the same as yours that is A + B'

Comment: @Lechius Ok, so now it must be correct, although the first equality doesn't seem trivial (to me, and that's probably part of the reason why it became so shorter).

Comment: well, but for example if AB is 1, ABC and ABC' are also 1, so I can say that AB = AB+ABC'+ABC. Why it doesn't seem trivial then? Is it wrong then?